# I have problems with terminal

Tags: command-line

[image]

I'm new to Linux and I have some problem with terminal I have never used Linux and I don't know anything about terminal. How can I solve this problem? Even I can't download anything from terminal like wine what should I do?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Terminal output is plain text.

Comment: You can change to another server in Software & Updates if the `az` one doesn't work well.

Comment: can I change it as main server? @Pilot6

Comment: You can use any server including main.

Comment: thank u very much it worked @Pilot6